# Opencart Journal 2 Theme Sticky Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opencart

I want to create a sticky header for the search, not the menu. Can someone tell me where should I change the code? I have found `journal.js` and `jquery.sticky.js`. Here's the clip code for `journal.js` about sticky menu:

```
Journal.enableStickyHeader = function (padding) {
var header = $('.header');
Journal.stickyHeaderHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
var lastScroll = 0;

$('.header-notice').each(function() {
    Journal.stickyHeaderHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
});

header.css('top', '-' + (Journal.stickyHeaderHeight) + 'px');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1 * (Journal.stickyHeaderHeight) ) {

        $('body').addClass('is-sticky').css('padding-top', Journal.stickyHeaderHeight + padding);

        header.css('top', 0);

        if (currentScrollPosition < lastScroll) {
            header.css('top', '-' + (Journal.stickyHeaderHeight) + 'px');
            $('.tablet .is-sticky .mega-menu').hide();
        }
        if(Journal.hasStickyScroll) {
            lastScroll = currentScrollPosition;
        }

    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('is-sticky').css('padding-top', padding);
    }
});
};
```

Sticky JS is used from here : http://stickyjs.com

I already change `$('header')` with `$('#search')` but still not working. Anybody here have same problem before? I'm using Journal 2 Theme and Opencart 1.5.6.4

Comment: which layout u r using in journal theme?

Comment: I'm using Journal 5 layout

Comment: catalog/view/theme/journal2/css/header.css at line no 2014 comment this class its will help you       .sticky-menu .is-sticky .journal-header-center .journal-top-header,
  .sticky-menu .is-sticky .journal-header-center .journal-center-bg,
  .sticky-menu .is-sticky .journal-header-center #header > .header-assets {
    display: none; }

Comment: Nope... still not working.. I believe it's not in css.. but at JS.. because when scroll down, the class is added to the div.. (just my thought)